# Splitting a string at the very beginning of a matched word

Tags: php, string, split

I'm trying to find out what function can split a given string so I come up with one substring beginning with the matched word and the other part. It's got a bit of a long since I started searching and I feel desperate, well so many functions on ways to split a string I just want your help to figure out what's the best way to do this splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr) can do this for you simply

Usage is:

```
 $fragment = strstr( $string, $search );
```

If you're running PHP 5.3 to get the part before the search term you can use the same function as:

```
 $fragment_before = strstr( $string, $search, true );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'hjae adj xyz asdj asdjs';

$search = 'xyz';
if(($pos = strpos($str, $search)) !== false)
{
    $before = substr($str, 0, $pos); // hjae adj 
    $after = substr($str, $pos); // xyz asdj asdjs
}
```

Comment: well strstr is much easier though this is a nice way to reach the same end ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

try [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) or [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to split a string. I'm not sure what you exactly want, but I would advise you to check [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).